# How to faster compute the count frequency of words in a large words list with python and be a dictionary

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.x, dictionary

There is a very long words list, the length of list is about 360000. I want to get the each word frequency, and to be a dictionary.

For example:

```
{'I': 50, 'good': 30,.......}
```

Since the word list is large,  I found it take a lot of time to compute it. Do you have faster method to accomplish this?

My code, so far, is the following:

```
  dict_pronoun = dict([(i, lst_all_tweet_noun.count(i)) for i in 
                        lst_all_tweet_noun])
  sorted(dict_pronoun)
```

Comment: `sorted(dict_pronoun)` returns a sorted list of keys. Dictionaries have no order (at least not until Python 3.6), so that line is entirely useless without storing the result.

Comment: create a associative array (columns are the words), check wether column exists => increment counter else add a new entry. at the end your just divide the value of each entry by the sum of your words

Comment: hi thanks for your comments. could you use the code to explain your guys method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong here:

- You are building a huge list first, then turn that list object into a dictionary. There is no need to use the `[..]` list comprehension; just dropping the `[` and `]` would turn it into a much more memory-efficient generator expression.
- You are using `dict()` with a loop instead of a `{keyexpr: valueexpr for ... in ...}` dictionary comprehension; this would avoid a generator expression altogether and go straight to building a dictionary.
- You are using `list.count()`, this does a **full scan** of the list for every element. You turned a linear scan to count N items into a O(N**2) quadratic problem. You could simply increment an integer in the dictionary each time you find the key already is present, set the value to 0 otherwise, but there are better options (see below).
- The `sorted()` call is busy-work; it returns a sorted list of keys that is then discarded again. Dictionaries are not sortable, not and produce a dictionary again at any rate.

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here to do your counting; it uses a linear scan:

```
from collections import Counter

dict_pronoun = Counter(lst_all_tweet_noun)
```

A `Counter` has a [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) which will efficiently give you output *sorted by counts*, which is what I suspect you wanted to achieve with the `sorted()` call.

For example, to get the top K elements (where K is smaller than N, the size of the dictionary), a `heapq` is used to get you those elements in O(NlogK) time (avoiding a full O(NlogN) sort).

Comment: thanks @Martijn Pieters for your detailed answer. I will confirm it with your suggested method and report it.